# How to create a Django project that used dynamic href {% url %} link to the submitted title page via its form?

Tags: python, html, django, forms, url

I can not set my url variable in my href, path and form action.
what to do, please?

Here are my wrote code files:

entry.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Content: {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>{{ title }}: </h1>
    <p>
        {{ Content }}
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

index.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for title in entries %}
            <li><a href="{% url 'entry' title='' %}">{{ title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

layout.html

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>
                <form action="{% url 'entry' title='' %}" method="get">
                    <input class="search" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Create New Page
                </div>
                <div>
                    Random Page
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from . import util


def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })

def entry(request, title):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
        "title": request.GET.get(title),
        "content": util.get_entry("request.GET.get(title)")
    })
```

url.py

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("entry/<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    ]
```

The following is the export error message page for the codes above:

## NoReverseMatch at /

```
Reverse for 'entry' with keyword arguments '{'title': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['entry/(?P<title>[^/]+)\Z']Request Method:   GETRequest URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/Django Version:   4.2.2Exception Type:    NoReverseMatchException Value:  Reverse for 'entry' with keyword arguments '{'title': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['entry/(?P<title>[^/]+)\Z']Exception Location:   /home/passenger80/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py, line 828, in _reverse_with_prefixRaised during: encyclopedia.views.indexPython Executable:  /home/passenger80/miniconda3/envs/wiki/bin/pythonPython Version:    3.10.6Python Path:  ["/media/passenger80/DATA/Engineering/My Profession/Coding/Git/CS50/CS50's Web "'Programming with Python and JavaScript/wiki','/home/passenger80/miniconda3/envs/wiki/lib/python310.zip','/home/passenger80/miniconda3/envs/wiki/lib/python3.10','/home/passenger80/miniconda3/envs/wiki/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload','/home/passenger80/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages','/home/passenger80/miniconda3/envs/wiki/lib/python3.10/site-packages']Server time: Mon, 17 Jul 2023 17:21:38 +0000Error during template renderingIn template /media/passenger80/DATA/Engineering/My Profession/Coding/Git/CS50/CS50's Web Programming with Python and JavaScript/wiki/encyclopedia/templates/encyclopedia/layout.html, error at line 15
```

```
Reverse for 'entry' with keyword arguments '{'title': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['entry/(?P<title>[^/]+)\Z']5 <html lang="en">6       <head>7         <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>8         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">9            <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">10     </head>11       <body>12            <div class="row">13             <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">14                   Wiki15                  <form action="{% url 'entry' title='' %}" method="get">16                       <input class="search" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">17                     <button type="submit">Submit</button>18                 </form>19                   <div>20                     Home21                  </div>22                    <div>23                     Create New Page24                   </div>25                    <div>
```

I have problem to define url expression in html and urlpattern set.
Thanks for your time.